# ¿Cuantos operadores UNION puede contener un SELECT: PL-SQL?

Tags: oracle, select, plsql, toad

tengo la siguiente duda, cuantos operadores `UNION` puede contener un `select`? Sintaxis básica del `UNION`.

```
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions]
UNION
SELECT expression1, expression2, ... expression_n
FROM tables
[WHERE conditions];
```

Se puede anidar mas `UNION` en la misma sentencia del `SELECT`?

Comment: Es una interesante pregunta, seguramente hay un límite, pero lamentablemente, una búsqueda en google, no arroja ningún dato al respecto. Tal vez antes de ese límite, tengas otro por la longitud total de la consulta SQL, según esto: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21643/limit.htm#TTREF456 es de 409,600 bytes.